# Are terms of use considered a contract from GDPR point of view?

Tags: gdpr, privacy, terms-of-service, service

If service terms of use doesn’t talk about setting up a contract between the company and the user, can you use «execution of contract» as the lawfulness for GDPR processing ?

If signup data is required to provide the service, do you need consent or does mentioning «by signing up you agree to the terms of use and privacy policy» enough ?

Comment: You might want to provide more context. I for one don't understand the question.

Comment: @IñakiViggers I’ve rephrased

Comment: The EDPB has published [in-depth guidance on the applicability of Art 6(1)(b) necessity for performance of a contract in the context of online services (PDF)](https://edpb.europa.eu/our-work-tools/our-documents/guidelines/guidelines-22019-processing-personal-data-under-article-61b_en). For example, it points out that this legal basis will only cover processing activities that are objectively necessary to fulfill the contract, so it's not possible to avoid true consent by mentioning things in a contract. But if Art 6(1)(b) applies, then no extra consent is necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your confusion might be caused by the fact that even with a contract, only the data necessary for that contract is covered under the GDPR. So yes, while there might be an "execution of contract" under the T&C, this would only cover necessary data.

That means you can't ask arbitrary signup data under the guise of a contract. If you need to deliver a physical product, you can store a physical address. If it's an online service, you can store an email address or similar handle. But you can't mix the two. A physical address is unnecessary for the execution of a contract that's not physical in nature.

Now, you mention "consent". Under GDPR, this is a distinct justification besides "execution of contract". You might have consent to store a physical address in addition to an online address, e.g. if you offer a customer to physically mail a password request form. This consent is additional to the contract.

Also note that the bit above only covers the lawful reasons for the processing of personal data (article 6). You also have to obey the other GDPR rules, e.g. fully inform the user, make sure that consent is freely given, etc.

Comment: To double on. Consent is separated from the contract. If you want some piece of information that is not needed to fulfill the contract, you need consent for it. And you cannot make the contract conditional on "consenting" to give that data; "Tell me your favorite Pokemon or I will not sell you the car" would go against GDPR.

Comment: So if you have a checkbox to  consent to the term of use on signup, then the legal justification for collecting data (here email/password + names and other optional fields) cannot be «execution of contract», it must then be «consent». Right ?

Comment: @borisrorsvort Agreement to a contract generally does not meet the GDPR's definition of “consent”. For example, you can't expect that users actually read your terms of service, but consent MUST be “informed”. It must also be possible to decline consent without negative consequences. Consent is typically only used as a legal basis when legally mandated (e.g. cookies, health data) or when no other legal basis is available (e.g. necessity for a contract or for a legitimate interest). It's good to be clear about the legal basis you're using because they result in different rights, e.g. erasure.

Comment: @borisrorsvort: You might need a somewhat better legal background. **Any** contract, GDPR or not, EU or UK or USA, requires consent of the contracting parties. Before there's consent, at best you have a proposal or an offer. But in GDPR terms, the word "consent" is used as a shorthand for one of the 6 justification grounds. That is another type of consent, distinct from the "execution of contract" justification.